# AngularJS doesn't parse dynamically loaded data from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I am trying to create N number of **Select** controls dynamically from directive based on array that is passed in from the attribute (where N is the length of the array).

Structure of an object of the array is as such:

```
selectDescription = {
    array: arrayObject, //ng-options, a string as 'item as item.name for item in selectArray[0]'
    change: methodName, //ng-change, actionname
    level: levelNumber //level number
}
```

So the number of **select controls** inside span tag depends on the number of `selectDescription(s)` that I get from the attribute.

**First select control is rendered successfully**. Subsequent select controls should have been rendered on select of an option from **previous rendered select** controls. **But it's not happening in my case**. Although I am successfully appending angular elements in the current **inputEl**(on select of an option), it is not being rendered in the UI. I guess I am missing something very crucial.

**On change of selectDescriptions**, a flipped attribute is set, through which I am able to call `scope.$editable.render()` from link, which in turn runs render function to re-append elements after clearing the previous HTML inside `span`.

My Code:

```
app.directive('editableLocation', function(editableDirectiveFactory) {  
    var createElement = function(el, index){
      var newElement = angular.element("<select/>");
      newElement.attr('ng-model','$data'+index);
      newElement.attr('ng-options',el.array);
      newElement.attr('ng-change',el.change.substring(0, el.change.length - 1)+", $data"+index+")");
      return newElement;
    }

var descriptions = [] ;
var dir = editableDirectiveFactory({
  directiveName: 'editableLocation',
  inputTpl: '<span></span>',
  render: function() {
    this.parent.render.call(this);
    this.inputEl.html("");
    for(var i = 0 ; i < descriptions.length ; i ++){
      this.inputEl.append(createElement(descriptions[i], i));
    }
  }
});
var linkOrg = dir.link;

dir.link = function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
   console.log(el);
   descriptions = scope.$eval(attrs.description);
   scope.$watch('flipped',function(newValue,oldValue){
        if(newValue != 0){
            scope.$editable.render();
        }
    });
    return linkOrg(scope, el, attrs, ctrl);
};

return dir;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are adding the dynamic HTML content in the `link` function of the Angular directive, Angular will not auto compile/parse it. You need to do it manually using `$compile` directive. So after you appended all the HTML, do the following (inject `$compile` in your code)

```
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

Where `element` is your any parent element where you are generating dynamic HTML and `scope` is the scope of the directive or any other scope which you want it to be attached to the dynamic HTML.

Comment: I did as you said. Although it's showing two select controls inside this.inputEl.contents(), it still doesn't render to same number of controls in the UI.

Comment: It might be a problem with your code. Can you provide a plunkr or fiddle?

Comment: I don't know, why the first select control is rendered but not the ones after that? I have tried almost everything to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `xeditable.js` I have found that xeditable renders the UI by calling a `show` method defined in its `editableController`.

It is defined as:

```
self.show = function() {
    self.setLocalValue();
    self.render(); //calls 'render' function of 'editableDirectiveFactory'; that' where my custom UI lies
    $element.after(self.editorEl); //attaches newelement(especially whole <form/> element)
    $compile(self.editorEl)($scope); //renders whole UI(and also the newly attached one)
    self.addListeners();
    $element.addClass('editable-hide');
    return self.onshow();
};
```

So what I felt is, I need to call this `show` method from my `link` function, which receives the `controller`.

This is what I did:

```
dir.link = function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {   
    $element = el;
    scope.$watch(attrs.flipped, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        //re-render element if flipped is changed; denoting description of select controls have been altered
        if (newValue != 0) {
            ctrl[0].show(); //this will call render function and also $compile({{content/html/element}})(scope)
        }
    });
    return linkOrg(scope, el, attrs, ctrl);
};
```

And also you need to hide the previous `<form/>` element(which contains previous rendered UI), so that only one forms get displayed.

This is how I hid that previous `<form/>` element in `render' function of`editableDirectiveFactory`:

```
var prevForm = $element[0].nextElementSibling; //hide previous form element which would already contain previous select
if (prevForm)
    prevForm.classList.add('editable-hide');
```

That solved my problem at least :)